# After i write form media in html template, i cannot upload everything

Tags: html, django, forms, ckeditor5

I want to add ckeditor5 in my template ,so i add {{form.media}} to my template.

After writing {{form.media}} code , i cannot upload everything.

It seems input tag not fuction it.

Please help me to figure out what happened!!

THX~~

my code is down below:

view

```
def post(request):
Form = PostForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
    Form = PostForm(request.POST)
    Form.save()
    return render(request, "Upload_done.html")
else:
    return render(request, "upload.html", {'Form': Form})
```

html

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
{{ Form.media }}
{{ Form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Upload">
```

form

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content']
```

model

```
class Post(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
content = CKEditor5Field(config_name='extends')
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: Try adding the `novalidate` attribute to your form tag, i.e. `<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>`

Comment: Thanks for helping me to solve this problem!!!
It works!!!

Comment: I'll post that as an answer then. :)

Comment: Allow me to ask why "novaliddate" works????

Comment: I have answered that below :)

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that `content` is rendered as a `textarea` and CKEditor *hides* it by adding some inline CSS to it's element. Most WYSIWYG editors don't directly change the contents of the form field with the users input and rather change the content when the form is *submitted*. This becomes a problem here because the browser tries to validate the form before submission but the field is *empty* (the JavaScript to fill it hasn't run yet) and it also has the `required` attribute.

Due to this your form is not submitted, adding onto the problem the error popup the browser should be displaying is also not displayed due to the CSS that is hiding the element. The solution to all this is to indicate to the browser to simply *not* validate the form by using the `novalidate` attribute on the form tag:

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
{{ Form.media }}
{{ Form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Upload">
```